# How install python hunspell on aws-lambda

Tags: pip, aws-lambda, apt

How to run

```
sudo apt install libhunspell-dev
```

command on `aws-lambda`?

I tried many ways like `serverless.yml` requirements.
And I am able to install `pip` packages.
But I would like to run `apt` commands.

Comment: You need to read about [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)